# How to guess/find types for strict usage of Typescript

Tags: typescript, callback

I wish to use Typescript in strict mode in my projects and I have the following problem.
I don't seem to always be able to find the type to specify.

---

Let me give an example.
Let's say I am using a third party library and assuming it has types definition.

```
import {foo} from "someLibrary"

foo((a, b) => {}); //foo function has a callback parameter
```

How am I suppose to get the type of *a* and *b* (stating that it is not explicitly written in the doc) ?

Wanted result :

```
foo((a: typeOfA, b: typeOfB) => {});
```

For a more concrete example, let's take [findOne](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-findOne) of mongoose :

```
Adventure.findOne({ country: 'Croatia' }, function (err, adventure) {});
```

How am I suppose to get the type of err and adventure ?

---

If this post is not clear enough, don't hesitate to ask for edit.

Thank you

Comment: Hover over `err` in your editor.

Comment: @vera This doesn't work. It only display any if nothing is specify. Do you use some specific extension maybe ?